# .Net SecureString in Java

Tags: java, wcf, wsdl, axis, securestring

I am trying to use a 3rd party authentication web service at a customer site. the web services was written in .Net and accepts SecureString as password type.

```
AuthResult Login(string username, SecureString passkey)
```

My app is written in Java and there is no compatible type for SecureString in Java that I can use :( When I generate an axis proxy, it generates a stub with no members for SecureString, and hence I am not able to make the authentication call to the service.

```
public class SecureString  implements java.io.Serializable {
    public SecureString() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I am trying http://sanguinecomputing.com/a-secure-string-implementation-for-long-term-storage-of-sensitive-data-in-java/ but I am not very hopeful

Can anyone help me with how to overcome this interoperability issue? I am looking for a way to send parameter of type secureString from Java app code to .Net Service.

Comment: You should be able to use a regular string.

Comment: I have no control over service

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Its not clear from "how to overcome this interoperability issue".  A `SecureString` implementation in Java? Or one that has the same methods as a C# `SecureString`? Or guidance on doing it in Java? The following may help: [SecureString filetype:java](https://www.google.com/search?q=securestring+filetype%3Ajava)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, I can say that the .Net type of `SecureString` is not inter-operable. I have put the request out to the Service Provider to write a service that takes `char[]` as parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly. SecureString is not a serializable type. It can never be, across machines, as SecureString relies on DPAPI, which itself relies on local machine properties to construct it's encryption key/vector.

The fact that an API was posted with a SecureString -type parameter shows a vital flaw in its design. No remote client could possibly hand that parameter in.

Answer (score 2):

> ... My app is written in Java and there is no compatible type for SecureString in Java
>
> ... Can anyone help me with how to overcome this interoperability issue?

As you know, there is no `SecureString` in Java.

In Java, you are supposed to use `char[]` and overwrite the material when you are finished with it. From [Using Password-Based Encryption](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html#PBEEx) in the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Reference Guide:

> It would seem logical to collect and store the password in an object
>   of type `java.lang.String`. However, here's the caveat: `Objects` of
>   type `String` are immutable, i.e., there are no methods defined that
>   allow you to change (overwrite) or zero out the contents of a String
>   after usage. This feature makes `String` objects unsuitable for
>   storing security sensitive information such as user passwords. You
>   should always collect and store security sensitive information in a
>   char array instead.

So your `SecureString` will have a private `char[]`, and you will zeroize the array on destruction. I believe .Net's `SecureString` masks the string when not in use (I don't believe its true encryption, but I could be wrong). So you'll need to provide a mask function, too.

Comment: Agreed and that's what a secureString does in .Net. But my question pertains to calling a SOAP service where one of the parameter in the method is of type SecureString. The generated stub class is literally empty, so I can't construct the parameters. Not even from char[]. If I was calling a service that I had control of, I would definitely change the parameter to char[]

Comment: My bad. I came to the question following the 'security' tag on it. Perhaps you can get the right folks involved with the appropriate tag (maybe WPF or COM or WSDL or similar?). I don't really keep up with the web technologies, so I don't know.

Comment: But can't the GC move any data around, including char arrays? So isn't there the possibility that the password remains at the original location in memory?

Comment: There is a really good comment regarding String vs char[] security from Stanimir Simeonoff under this article: http://securesoftware.blogspot.cz/2009/01/java-security-why-not-to-use-string.html

Comment: @jww SecureString does encrypt its contents using DPAPI.  The encryption is done by the OS which also manages the symmetric encryption keys.

Comment: Elasticsearch seems to have an implementation: https://static.javadoc.io/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.1.1/org/elasticsearch/common/settings/SecureString.html